# How to prove that $2\sqrt{a^{ea}b^{eb}}\ge a^{eb}+b^{ea}$ for $a > 0, b > 0$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $a,b\in R^{+}$. Show that
$$2a^{\frac{ea}{2}}b^{\frac{eb}{2}}\ge a^{eb}+b^{ea} \>.$$

**My attempt**

I know the following inequality is true:
$$a^{ea}+b^{eb}\ge a^{eb}+b^{ea} \>.$$

See [this post on AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=118722) or S. Manyama (2010), [Solution of One Conjecture on Inequalities with Power-Exponential Functions](http://ajmaa.org/searchroot/files/pdf/v7n2/v7i2p1.pdf), *The Australian Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications*, vol. 7, no. 2.

But my problem is much stronger (because $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$) and I can't solve it.

Comment: How is this possible? $\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt {ab}$ from A.M-G.M inequality

Comment: @GTXOC Doesn't look like AM-GM can be used here.

Comment: @DanShved but isn't the A.M.-G.M. always applicable for real numbers?

Comment: @GTXOC In this example, the two terms under the radical are not the two terms in the sum on the right.

Comment: This is inequality is very very stronger and Hard.I hope someone can solve it.Thank you,This inequality is my found it.and is true.

Comment: @GTXOC It is always applicable to positive numbers, but in this case it doesn't seem to say anything useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $b=a/2$ :

\begin{align*}\frac{RHS}{LHS} &=  \frac{a^{ea/2}+(a/2)^{ea}}{2 a ^{ea/2 }(a/2)^{e(a/2)/2}} \\ &= \frac{1}{2(a/2)^{ea/4}} + \frac{a^{ea/4}}{2^{1+3ea/4}}\end{align*}

which tends to $\infty$ as $a\to\infty$, because $\displaystyle\frac{a^{ea/4}}{2^{1+3ea/4}} \to \infty$.

This means that for all large enough $a$, the pairs $(a,b)=(a,a/2)$ are counterexamples.

Comment: (+1) Indeed, even the most crude analysis of the second term in your display equation shows that $a = 2^{1 / 2 e} \cdot 8 \leq 9.09$ is already enough.

Comment: It may also be worth pointing out that if we replace the RHS of the OP's first equation with the corresponding geometric mean, namely $2 a^{eb/2} b^{ea/2}$, the result becomes (almost trivially) true. Thus, the analogous GM version of the second inequality in the OP's post is true. (The HM version is not.)

Comment: @cardinal I see, that version follows from the rearrangement inequality directly, right?

Comment: Or, just assume, without loss of generality, that $b \geq a$ and divide. :-)

Comment: @cardinal ha, true :)